# Slim framework 3 path/route for images

Tags: php, slim-3

I have the following structure:

```
index.php
/app
/images
```

I have routes setup for all the different pages and whatnot but when I try to access an image directly it tries to pick that route up as one of my dynamic routes.

So for context, I am converting this from a pre-existing app and to maintain the links/paths that it had, I have a completely dynamic route at the end of the index:

```
$app->get('/{page}', 'HomeController:processRequest');
$app->get('/{page}/{id}', 'ProductController:viewProduct');
$app->get('/{page}/{id}/{show}', 'ProductController:viewProduct');
```

So when I do the following in an image tag:

```
https://example.com/images/nav/tinycheck.png
```

That route kicks in and it fails.  Is there any way to tell Slim to ignore anything with 'images' in the path and just serve up the image?

I have tried looking at a bunch of other threads on here but nothing is pointing me to the answer.

Comment: Do you use Apache?

Comment: Yes, I do.  Why do you ask?  .htaccess trickery?  I thought about going that route but I wanted everything to be run through slim.

Comment: Routing everything through php and slim (even images/css/js) is not very efficient. A tiny [.htaccess](https://gist.github.com/odan/d2b889c350aa2ea0ff8e5ca93ce588a2#front-controller) and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

I seem to have resolved it with the following:

```
$app->get('/images/nav/{data}', function($request, $response, $args) {    
    $data = $args['data'];
    $image = @file_get_contents("/mypath/images/nav/".$data);
   if($image === FALSE) {
       $handler = $this->notFoundHandler;
       return $handler($request, $response);    
    }

    $response->write($image);
    return $response->withHeader('Content-Type', FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
});
```